# Liferay 7 How to preserve current page value to display when it is backed from another page

Tags: liferay

I use Liferay 7.0, my project require a lot of input screen like below flow:

Input page 1 -> input page 2 -> input page 3 -> input page 4

So I am considering how to preserve each page's current value so that when I back from other page like below flow then it can show inputted values:

```
`Input page 1 <= input page 2 <= input page 3 <= input page 4`
```

I tried to use redirect like:
    `<portlet:actionURL var="myAction">`

```
`<portlet:param name="redirect" value="<%=themeDisplay.getURLCurrent()%>"/>`

`<portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/myPage.jsp"/>`

`</portlet:actionURL>`
```

and in the next page I used:
 `<liferay-ui:header backURL="<%=redirect%>" title='Back' />`

even it could not back to previous pages.
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<%
    String redirect =request.getAttribute("redirect");

%>
<liferay-ui:header backURL="<%=redirect%>" title='Back' />
```

Comment: I tried with:

String backURL = ParamUtil.getString(request, "redirect");

And the link of current page is correct but when I lick back then nothing change, the screen is not changed even browse's link was changed.